# service fabric running .net 6.0 application

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We are migrating our application from .NET 4.6.1 to .NET 6.0.
after deploying the migrated application, it is failing to find framework dlls. After logging into cluster VM looks like .NET 6.0 is not installed on machines. Do we have to have to separately install .NET 6 on cluster?

existing cluster is configured for auto fabric upgrade and current fabric version is 9.0.1028.9590

Thanks

Comment: Please check this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade-version-azure) and [migrate asp.net 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks for links i have checked them but they are for upgrading application code .net version. my SF runing is already set to auto upgrade and running on latest version. But my question is how to install .NET 6.0 runtime on cluster VMs.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need to install .NET frameworks on Service Fabric - this should be bundled as part of your Service Fabric application packages. We recently went through the exact process of upgrading our applications and I can also confirm that our cluster does not have any recent .NET frameworks installed.

**How do you create your deployment packages?** I suspect this *may* be the source of your problem...

For example, if using Azure DevOps, basically you need the following build tasks:

- Use Net Core => to install 6.0.x SDK
- Restore nuget packages
- Build your .sln file via VS Studio build task
- Build your .sfproj file via another VS Studio build task with parameters  `/t:Package /p:PackageLocation=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\applicationpackage`
- And publish artifact using source `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`

Finally, use the default powershell script `Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1` that comes with default VS Studio to register and deploy your application to cluster.